# Failed to concatenation with my custom string class

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, output, concatenation

I have nearly finished creating my own custom string class. However, it seems not going well when the program did not return the output that I was expected. In detail:

> **Input:**
>
> string a = "Hello"
>
> string b = "World!"
>
> **Expected output:**
>
> HelloWorld!
>
> !dlroWolleH
>
> **Actual output:**
>
> Hello

Here is my code:

```
#ifndef _STRING
#define _STRING
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
class string {
private:
    char* s = nullptr;
    unsigned int size = 0;
public:
    string();
    ~string() { delete s; };
    string(char* );
    string(const char* );
    string(const string&);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, string&);
    friend string operator +(string, string);
    string& operator = (const string&);
    string& operator = (const char&);     
    string& inverse();
    char* inconst();
    char* output() const{
        return s;
    }
};
#endif
string::string() :s{ nullptr } {
    size = 1;
    s = new char[size];
    s[0] = '\0';
}
string::string(char* source) {
    if (source == nullptr) {
        size = 1;
        s = new char[size];
        s[0] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        size = strlen(source) + 1;
        s = new char[size];
        s[size - 1] = '\0';
        for (size_t k = 0; k < (size - 1); k++) {
            s[k] = source[k];
        }
    }
}
string::string(const char* source) {
    if (source == nullptr) {
        size = 1;
        s = new char[size];
        s[0] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        size = strlen(source) + 1;
        s = new char[size];
        s[size - 1] = '\0';
        for (size_t k = 0; k < (size - 1); k++) {
            s[k] = source[k];
        }
    }
}
string::string(const string& t) {
    size = t.size;
    s = new char[size];
    s[size - 1] = '\0';
    for (size_t k = 0; k < (size - 1); k++) {
        s[k] = t.s[k];
    }
}
string& string::operator=(const string& source) {
    delete[] s;
    size = source.size;
    s = new char[size];
    s[size - 1] = '\0';
    for (size_t k = 0; k < (size - 1); k++) {
        s[k] = source.s[k];
    }
    return *this;
}
string& string::operator=(const char&source) {
    const char* t = &source;
    if (t == nullptr) {
        size = 1;
        s = new char[size];
        s[0] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        size = strlen(t) + 1;
        s = new char[size];
        s[size - 1] = '\0';
        for (size_t k = 0; k < (size - 1); k++) {
            s[k] = t[k];
        }
    }
    return* this;
}
string operator +(string a, string b) {
    string t;
    t.size = a.size + b.size;
    t.s = new char[t.size + 1];
    strncpy_s(t.s, a.size + 1, a.s, a.size);
    strncpy_s(t.s + a.size, b.size + 1, b.s, b.size);
    return t;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, string& source) {
    os << source.output();
    return os;
}

char* string::inconst() {
    char* t;
    t = new char[size + 1];
    for (size_t k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        t[k] = s[size - 1 - k];
    }
    t[size] = '\0';
    return t;
}
string& string::inverse() {
    this->s = this->inconst();
    return*this;
}
    int main(){
        string a = "Hello";
        string b = "World!";
        string c = a + b;
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
        std::cout << c.inverse() << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

It seems like that I have caught some errors at concatenation part ( overloading operator + assignment) since I can receive the output i want when i output separated variable `a` or `b` like `std::cout << b << std::endl;` but I cannot find out exactly what I was wrong. Please help me fix my code and thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `string` does store the terminating null character at `s[size - 1]`.

Then in `inconst` you take the null character not into account, but pretend that `size` is number of characters in the string.

> ```
> char* string::inconst() {
>     char* t;
>     t = new char[size + 1];               // why +1 here ?
>     for (size_t k = 0; k < size; k++)     
>     {
>         t[k] = s[size - 1 - k];
>     }
>     t[size] = '\0';                      // why another \0 ?
>     return t;
> }
> ```

The first iteration assigns `s[size-1]` to `t[0]`, ie in the end the string stored in `t` looks like this:

```
t[0]  t[1]        ...   t[size] t[size+1]
\0    s[size-2]   ...   s[0]    \0
```

You need to decide if `size` does count the null terminator or not and then be consistent about that.

---

Presumably this won't be the last time you need to do debugging, hence I propose to instrument the `operator<<` to print more information and not rely on the `char*` overload. Write a loop that prints character by character. If I didnt miss anything and my answer is correct you will see the contents of your string as explained above.

---

There are more issues in your code, the one I spotted is `operator=` not handling self assignment correctly. When you do

```
string s;
s = s;
```

Then your `operator=` first deletes the buffer and then copies from it. Just in case you are not convinced that this is an issue (because who would write `s=s`, thats silly, no?), consider for example a function `void foo(string& a, string b&) { a = b; }`.

---

On a more stylistic note, I suggest you to rename the method. `inverse` suggests that it would return a new `string`, while `invert` would make it clear that it modifies the string. (And I have no clue what `inconst` is supposed to mean.)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I have caught bugs at the loop. I will also notice about naming constructors and assignments. By the way, "intconst" means inverting constructor